# How to lock recorded cells in a macro file and make them of a different color(also locked)

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have finally found the code for my macro sheet, just need some finishing touches. I want to lock the values in Recorded cells(As in image attached) and make them of a different color(also locked)for visually better look.

[image: img1]

I need to keep them unaffected while I modify other cells in the sheet.

My Current Code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Add_Nos(myRow As Long, myCol As Long, ByRef myTarget As Range)

Dim r As Long, c As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
r = .Cells(myRow, "A").Value
c = .Cells(1, myCol).Value
End With

If myTarget.Value = r + c Then
myTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
myTarget.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If

End Sub

'===============================================================

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
Add_Nos Target.Row, Target.Column, Target
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You've shown no effort to actually solve your problem. Have you researched how to lock cells and protect worksheets? Once you have it protected properly and the specific cells locked you should not need to modify in your code; unless you are modifying locked cells in the code. Then you can unprotect in code, make changes, then reprotect.

Comment: Hey, I'm a noob in Excel vba. Currently, my motive was to just get a bit of its knowledge in order to have the sheet to work upon. I researched some basic parts and formed a code, then asked for my errors here and finally needed some finishing touches. In my search over the net, I didn't found much helpful info, and I don't have much utility for a deep study in this topic. Though, I welcome your comment. In regards to the solution, I tried but after unprotecting again the cells came back to original configuration.